# Singlethread, Multithread, Synchronous, Asynchronous - How do these combine?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, multicore

Every illustration and explanation concerning this topic that I came across do not seem to be consistent with each other.

I illustrated my understanding of the combinations of these concepts. **Can anyone confirm if its correct or erroneous?**

*The execution timeline in the illustration goes from left to right.*

[image]

Comment: What does "task" mean here?

Comment: In single-core multi-threading, you should expect the OS/CPU to do a lot of context switches between the threads. They will not nicely align with "tasks" in the code.

Comment: In single-threading on multiple cores, you can't have the same thread doing multiple things at once (or: the same thread being executed at multiple cores at once), that's not what a thread does. The OS might reschedule the thread to jump between cores, but usually tries to avoid that.

Comment: Regarding your definition of a "task", tasks can be interrupted an any moment in a mainstream multithreaded system so they can be split in many parts. The concept of "synchronous" multithreaded program running on a multicore machine is ambiguous/vague. It can apply to each thread separately or all of them regarding the async system. It is not rare to see async systems be dependent of a threading layer (which is rather a bad design) because threads are often use to asynchronously execute tasks while this is not required (as you shown).

Comment: By the way, your picture indicates that thread 1 can be executed on 2 core simultaneously which is not possible in practice. 1 thread is executed on at most 1 core at a time. 2 threads tends to to be executed on 2 (available) cores simultaneously except when there are other pending ready threads.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment, not an answer

---

Your pictures show threads executing tasks. IMO, that is unnecessary.

I think that part of what you are struggling with is the fact that threads belong to a lower layer of abstraction than anything that is called `async` in any programming system (i.e., in any language or library or framework.) If I may offer a weak analogy; If an `async` system is like a parcel delivery service, then tasks are like the packages that need to be delivered, and threads are like the trucks that carry them. If you want to understand how a truck works, you don't need to know specifics of the cargo that it carries. But if you want to know how FedEx works, then talking about the packages—where they are supposed to go, when they are supposed to arrive—is the very heart of the matter.

Note: I am not saying that every `async` feature in every programming system that has one is built on a lower layer of threads, but I would not be surprised if that was true in at least a few cases.

Anyway, my point is, if you are trying to draw a picture that illustrates the scheduling of N threads on M processors (where N > M), then there is no need to mention "task" anywhere. It only complicates the picture.

---

P.S.; You said, "Asynchronous," but you did not mention any specific programming language or library or framework. IMO, "asynchronous" is a vague idea—not nearly as well defined as "thread." If you want to know more about some specific `async` feature of some language or library or framework, then you should mention it by name. They don't necessarily all work in the same way.